# Calculate Growth rate of one day

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given that a population doubles in $4.8$ days. Now I need to calculate the growth rate of one day. This question is in the topic of the Malthus model.

To get the intrinsic growth rate: birth rate - death rate

Therefore: $2 - 1 = 1$
Therefore the growth rate is $1$ for $ 4.8$ days, how do I calculate it/convert the growth rate for $1$ day?

Comment: There are several notions of growth rate. One is the $r$ in the equation $P(t)=P(0)e^{rt}$. Another is $\frac{P(1)-P(0)}{P(0)}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How can you assume that the growth rate is exponential? It doesn't specify that it's of the form $$\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t}=kP\quad ;$$ it just says that it doubles in 4.8 days.

Comment: You are certainly right that one should not assume it. My guess, however, is that the problem-setter expects one to assume it.

Answer (score 0):

In general the equation is $p(t)= p(0)\cdot (1+g)^t$. If the Population doubles in 4.8 days, the equation

leads to $2\cdot p(0)= p(0)\cdot (1+g)^{4.8}$. Dividing by $p(0)$.

$2=(1+g)^{4.8}$

taking the 4.8th root

$2^{1/48}=1+g$

Solve for g and you have the growth rate.